# JQuery create chat tab by clicking on contact from contact list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd love if you could help me out w/ this issue I'm having. I'm trying to create a list of contacts, like the following, and then be able to open a chat tab for that contact. Somehow,it seems like the JQuery isn´t working, I'd appreciate if you could give me a hand.

1st piece (HTML contact)

```
<div id="contact-list">
    <div class="contact-line">
        <button class="contact-name">111111111</button>
        <div class="status"><div class="online"></div></div>
        <div class="user-photo"></div>
        <div class="unread-wrap"><div class="unread">2</div></div>  
    </div>
    .....
</div>


<ul id="ConversationsHeaderList">
</ul>
```

2nd Piece (JQuery)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.contact-name').click( function() {
                var $chatHeaderContent1 = $(this).parent().html();
                var $chatHeaderContent2 = $chatHeaderContent1 + '<button class="ConversationClose" title="Close Conversation"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
                $('#ConversationsHeaderList').append($chatHeaderContent2);
            });
        </script>
```

Somehow, I can´t make it create something like this:

```
<ul id="ConversationsHeaderList">
<li class="ConversationsHeader">
    <button class="contact-name">Friend 1</button>
    <div class="status"><div class="online"></div></div>
    <div class="user-photo"></div>
    <div class="unread-wrap"><div class="unread">1</div></div>
    <button class="ConversationClose" title="Close Conversation"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>          
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have wrap in a li element

Comment: Is it the div for the contact line?

Comment: I have added the answer, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this, you just have to wrap the content in li element
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.contact-name').click( function() {
            var $chatHeaderContent1 = $(this).parent().html();
            var $chatHeaderContent2 = '<li  class="ConversationsHeader">' + $chatHeaderContent1 + '<button class="ConversationClose" title="Close Conversation"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' + '</li>';
            $('#ConversationsHeaderList').append($chatHeaderContent2);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: OK. I'll give it a try. I'll give you my feedback asap.

Comment: No problem. Do accept the answer since it works. Whole point of ansking and answering a question.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to do that. I tried to up vote, but it didn't allowed me, 'cause of my reputation.